How to query a large file using pandas (or an alternative)?
I want to query a large file that I generated from the dbSNP VCF (16GB) using this shell command:
gzcat 00-All.vcf.gz | grep -v ## | awk -v FS='\t' -v OFS='\t' '{print $3, $1, $2, $4, $4}' | gzip > 00-All_relevant.vcf.gz

From this 00-All_relevant.vcf.gz I want to query multiple rsIDs (column ID in the MRE) and retrieve the corresponding genomic location and change (columns #CHROM, POS, REF, ALT). I use pandas for my project so I started with trying pandas for this too. I am open to other Python compatible options though.
I cannot read the whole file at once since my kernel always crashes, if using this command:
import pandas as pd

rsid_df = pd.read_csv('00-All_relevant.vcf.gz',
                      sep='\t')

That's why i tried reading it in chunks and after implementing user27243451's solution I came up with that solution:
rsid_df = pd.read_csv('00-All_relevant.vcf.gz',
                      sep='\t',
                      chunksize=1000000)

rsids = ['rs537152180','rs376204250','rs181326522']
variants = pd.DataFrame()

for data in rsid_df:
    rsid_found = data['ID'].isin(rsids)
    if rsid_found.astype(int).sum() > 0:
        variant = data.loc[rsid_found]
        variants = pd.concat([variants,variant])
        for id in variant['ID'].tolist():
            rsids.remove(id)
        if not rsids:
            break

print(variants)

This works, but it's terribly slow, especially if one of the rsIDs is on the last chunk. Is there any way to speed this up?

This is grossly inefficient because you're imagining dataframes as pure python structures, and they're not. Not only that but you're missing concepts of lookup complexity. if key in data['col1'].tolist(): does two things wrong - firstly it creates a list on every iteration and secondly, it does a lookup in a list, which is O(N) rather than O(1) in "Big O" analysis. To give a definitive answer, you would need some [mcve]

Separately, even the idiomatic approach to pandas would still be doing an O(N) lookup. Depending on your example and needs, we could probably beat it with a generic python dictionary. Indexes are not as efficient as they could be

The problem with this is that I cannot even read the entire file. So you saying, it would be better to build a dictionary. maybe with with open() as file and then add line from for line in file to the dict and query this? Or should I maybe make an external db an query this?

A DB like SQLite might help, or you could try a LazyFrame from polars, or maybe DuckDB (but I don't have experience with the latter). It still depends on the example you give.

Please give an example for the key you want to find and the expected output

You either do -> df[df['col1'] == key] or if you want multiple items, you can use isin - > df[df['col1'].isin(['find_this'])] and add multiple items in the list. You can add .head(1) after the line if you want only the first item, but you should check some tutorials for pandas.  Basic filters is one of the first thing you learn and you don't need a for loop for that.

I updated the question a little to elaborate my intention a little.

Accordingly to Pandas documentation, read_csv invoked with the chunksize argument returns a collection of dataframes.
Your approach is generally correct. We can optimize the for by using the isin() operator as already pointed out by others.
I refactor a bit your code with more explicit names and the additional variable c_ to explain the dataframe filtering by boolean arrays.
import pandas as pd

df_collection = pd.read_csv('large_file.gz',
                 chunksize=1000000)

keys = ["find_this", "and that"] # elements of column 1

for df in df_collection:
    c_ = df['col1'].isin(keys)   # returns an array of booleans with True where the condition is satisfied
    if c_.astype(int).sum() > 0: # if there are some True in the array, print and exit the loop
        print("found\n", df.loc[c_]) 
        break
else:
    print("Not found")


Thanks for this solution. However, wouldn't the loop also break, if there would only be one of the keys be found?

At least, if the two keys would be located in different chunks.

Yes, the loop will brake at first found key, as in your example code.   If this is not what you want... it is a perfect example why making a minimal reproducible example covering all your requirement it is so important.

Your right. I tried to update my question also considering your solution already.

If I understand your problem correctly, you can read and return one row from your dataset at a time using the following code:
def stream_rows(path, max_len):
    with gzip.open(path, 'rt', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        next(file)  # Skip the header
        for line in file:
            first_col = line[:max_len]  # Extract the first column up to max_len characters
            yield first_col


def get_minibatch(row_stream, size, key):
    try:
        for _ in range(size):
            row = next(row_stream)
            if row == key:
                return True  # Key found
    except StopIteration:
        pass  # End of stream reached
    
    return False  # Key not found


Now you can read the rows of a CSV file without loading it entirely into RAM. You can use these functions as shown below:
row_stream=stream_rows(path, 20)
found=get_minibatch(row_stream,1000, key)


You can search about out-of-core methods for loading a large datasets in python. There are other ways to deal with this situations as well
